# How to use pipe operator , arrow operator to find something or save the output in a file help.txt?

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, pipe

can anybody help

```
git > help.txt #works
git commit > help.txt #works
git commit -h > help.txt #never worked..
```

And similarly pipe operator doesn't work...

```
git commit -h | findstr branch #never works, but
git commit | finsdstr branch #works
```

Comment: Have you tried `|&` instead of `|`, and `&>` instead of `>`?

Comment: Which is it; cmd or bash?

Comment: If this is on Windows, I'd guess that `git commit -h` returns to _STDERR_ rather than _STDOUT_; so you'd have to do `git commit -h 2> help.txt` and `git commit -h 2>&1 | findstr "branch"`...

Comment: what are you trying to solve with this? Why would you need to pipe stdout of just git or git commit to a file?

Comment: actually, I usually need to search the help pages with findstr, and whenever I give the commands some switches to operate with like -h(in case of git commit -h), findstr fails to get the results. I wonder there are things like stderr and stdout, I didn't know that.

@oguzismail suggestion worked amazing. It would be amazing if you could tell the meaning of the operators, like what does |& and 2|  does because both works fine.
And what is 2> and 2>&1 represents..

Comment: And I don't know how to set some one's comment as answer, I'm new to stackoverflow.
CAn andbody tell please...